# Xcode: How do I write in turn-based image uploads?

Tags: ios, xcode, gallery

I'm new to xcode and am curious where to begin. Within the app I'm developing I want there to be a function that allows users that are part of sub-groups to upload image files to a collective gallery, but only one at a time. I.E User 1 is prompted that it is their turn to upload, User 2 can't upload an image until User 1 has successfully uploaded theirs... Any ideas on where to start, with this seemingly simple idea?

Comment: User 1 and User 2 are respectively using app to upload image? Not using two thread in one app, is it?

Comment: Are you talking multiple users using the same copy of the app on the same device, or multiple users, each with their own copy, running on their own device and uploading to a common server? Those are very different problems.

Comment: multiple users using the same copy of the app on their device. device is connected to a database. upload privileges would only apply to one person in a chain at a time